# No Vim Syntax Highlighting in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, vim

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 and I'm not getting any syntax highlighting.

I can turn syntax on/off via the `:syntax` command, but it has no effect on cpp and js files (haven't tested other files).

I installed vim via `apt-get install vim`, so it's not `vim-tiny`.

Below is my vim --version

```
vim --version

    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
    Included patches: 1-1689
    Extra patches: 8.0.0056
    Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
    Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
    Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    +acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
    +arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
    +autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
    -balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
    -browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
    ++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
    +byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
    +channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
    +cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
    -clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
    -clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
    +cmdline_compl   +job             -perl            +vertsplit
    +cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
    +cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
    +comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
    +conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
    +cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
    +cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
    +cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
    +cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
    +dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
    +diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
    +digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
    -dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
    -ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
    +emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
    +eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
    +ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
    +extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
       system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
         user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
     2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
          user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
      fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
    Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
    Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Any suggestions?  I'm not sure what to look at from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I needed to specify the number of colors available via the command

```
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: What command where? From the  vim : prompt? Or maybe an rc file?

Comment: That's correct Mike.  I put it in my .vimrc file, but you can also run it from the prompt inside vim itself.

Answer (score 1):

For others coming here with Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04:
For me the problem was that it was a stock vi install, not vim (not a symlink to vim). So just install vim:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Which sets up vi symlinks to vim, adding syntax highlighting support.

Comment: Yeah that's a common problem (although not the one the OP had)